# PHP - Get links from within an element after element has been found

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

I have the following code....

```
<div class="outer">
<div>
<h1>Christmas</h1>
 <ul>
  <li>Holiday</li>
  <li>Fun</li>
  <li>Joy</li>
 </ul>
<h1>4th July</h1>
 <ul>
  <li>Fireworks</li>
  <li>Happy</li>
  <li>Spectral</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
<div>
<h1>Christmas2</h1>
 <ul>
  <li>Holiday</li>
  <li>Fun</li>
  <li>Joy</li>
 </ul>
<h1>4th July</h1>
 <ul>
  <li>Fireworks2</li>
  <li>Happy</li>
  <li>Spectral</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I already know that I can find the DIV and then look inside the DIV for the elements etc by doing...

```
$doc->loadHTML($output);    //$output being the text above
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query('//div[@class="outer"]');  //Check outer
```

I know this above 3 lines will get the elements from within the DIV listed, but what I really want to be able to do is get the text of the [H1], then display the [li] values next to each H1..

the output i'm looking for is...

```
Christmas - Holiday, Fun, Joy
4th July - Fireworks, Happy, Spectral
Christmas2 - Holiday, Fun, Joy
4th July2 - Fireworks, Happy, Spectral
```

Comment: Show what you've tried... I see no effort in trying to solve your problem. What you're doing is asking for an answer, not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can continue to use xpath to traverse the elements on the header and get its following sibling, the list. Example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($output);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query('//div[@class="outer"]/div');
if($elements->length > 0) {
    foreach($elements as $div) {
        foreach ($xpath->query('./h1', $div) as $e) {
            $header = $e->nodeValue;
            $list = array();
            foreach ($xpath->query('./following-sibling::ul/li', $e) as $li) {

                $list[] = $li->nodeValue;
            }

            echo $header . ' - ' . implode(', ', $list) . '<br/>';
        }
        echo '<hr/>';
    }   
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2JjuOm)

Comment: Ghost I had to make a change to my request cause I thought it would still work if i modified it, but some reason it won't work can you please help with the revised version up top?

Comment: @MattHam if thats the case, then just modify the first query, since it has another div inside `$elements = $xpath->query('//div[@class="outer"]/div[@class="inner"]');`

Comment: your 100% right, but i meant to not have a class on that one is what i meant... I thought if i got the basics i would be able to understand and modify your code since i'm coming from ASP.NET but apparently i'm not as good as i thought.  The above is EXACTLY the structure of what i'm trying to understand how to pull the data from. a million thanks

Comment: @MattHam you keep changing the question, you should have done the final one in the first place. anyways, check the revision

Comment: Thanks a ton!  Well I wanted to try and learn it myself you know? But after an hour of trying to understand it I just gave up, apologies.

Comment: @MattHam glad this helped, anyways there are no shortage of resources here on SO. good day

Answer (score 0):

I've used [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) for this type of issue in the past:

```
// include phpquery
require('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');
// initialize
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($markup);
// get the text from the various elements
$h1Value = $doc['h1:first']->text(); // Christmas
// ... etc.
```

*(untested)*